# Find primitive-$n$-th roots of unity over finite field $\mathbb{F}_a$??

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, integers, primitive-roots

Is there efficient methods to find primitive-$n$-th roots of unities over $\mathbb{F}_a$??

In other word, find $\zeta$ such that,

$\zeta^n \equiv 1 $

where $\zeta \in \mathbb{F}_a$

Also, is there efficient methods to find primitive-$n$-th roots of unities over $\mathbb{Z}_a$??

In other word, find $\zeta$ such that,

$\zeta^n \equiv 1 \mod a$

where $\zeta \in \mathbb{Z}_a$

Comment: This depends on the size of the parameters. How is the field given to you? Often enough $\Bbb{F}_a$ is given as $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(p(x))$, where $p(x)$ is a primitive polynomial. In that case an $n$th primitive root is given by the recipe $x^{(a-1)/n}+(p(x))$. Even with some black box description of $\Bbb{F}_a$ you can take the non-deterministic approach of raising random elements of the field to power $(a-1)/n$ (which is fast by square-and-multiply). Of course, quick testing of whether such a candidate actually is of order $n$ requires you to know a factorization of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the answer is negative. If you would have such an algorithm then you'd have an efficient algorithm for factorizing large Mersenne's numbers...

Comment: By "efficient" I mean **computationally efficient**.

Comment: AKS is an efficient algorithm for testing primality.

Comment: Yes but what about factorisation of large Mersenne numbers?

Comment: Thanks all. Basically shouldn't we have to do brute force search?

Comment: As far I know yes

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account the remark of @mathma